How to get correct rotation of bones with copy constraints on a Curve deformed Mesh?
I am trying to make a plane with a few loopcuts, for correct deformation, to move along a Curve deform that I want to use as its animation path.
however I want to implement it into a game with a set animation.
that's why I added empties to the multiple vertex groups I made to copy its rotations and locations with constraints. then added bones with a copy transform constraint that target the empties.
this sort of works but I am encountering an issue when the path/curve does a loop, the bones don't rotate the correct way.
I want the rotation to follow the curve. and the bones to keep moving in a "conga line " formation IYKWIM.
